# How to set Font Features for whole Flutter app

Tags: flutter

So my colleague designer decided it was a great idea to use "Font Features" on the fonts of an app I'm developing.

The font features are enabled on all the text of the designs.

I know I can set font features for each individual text using the `fontFeatures` parameter in `TextStyle`.

```
Text(
  'Some text',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontFeatures: [
      FontFeature.stylisticSet(2),
      FontFeature.stylisticSet(3),
      FontFeature.stylisticSet(4),
    ],
  ),
);
```

But I don't know how to set them for all the Text widgets in the project.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this in the pre-existing 'Theme' setup in order to have it reflect for all Text widgets.

You could potentially create your own custom style class which you can then call within any Text widgets throughout the app.

Something like:

```
class CustomTextStyle {
  static TextStyle fontFeatureStyle(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.copyWith(
      fontFeatures: [ 
        FontFeature.stylisticSet(2),
        FontFeature.stylisticSet(3),
        FontFeature.stylisticSet(4),
      ]);
   }
}
```

implemented:

```
Text(
 'Sample Text',
  style: CustomTextStyle.fontFeatureStyle(context),
),
```